# How to use kubectl cp to copy files automatically from a local system to kubernetes Pods with list filter

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes

I have many pods in a kubernetes system with randomly name wordpress.xxx.xx.

Here the list of [pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Jxw.png)

I want to use one command with `kubectl cp` in other to copy files to all pods from one deployment.

In my case I don't want to use volumes because they mount into a path that already the existing content of that folder will be hidden.

How to do that, please?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there. You'll be great at this. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `kubectl cp` command copies files to a single container in a pod. To copy files in multiple containers easily, the below shell script can be used.

```
for pod in `kubectl get pods -o=name | grep wordpress | sed "s/^.\{4\}//"`; do echo "copying to $pod"; kubectl cp file.txt $pod:/; done
```

or

```
for pod in `kubectl get pods -o=name | grep wordpress | sed "s/^.\{4\}//"`
do
    echo "copying file to $pod"
    kubectl cp file.txt $pod:/
done
```

Both the scripts are same, single vs multi-line.