# How to update application code which is deployed to Kubernetes (EKS)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have configured the cluster for guestbook-go application by using EKS https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/guestbook-go

and followed the official tutorial
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html

Let's say I want to amend `public/index.html` file. In a Docker file I can see that the file is copied to the container:

`COPY ./public/index.html public/index.html`

In the `guestbook-controller.json` I can see the image that it was used:
`"image":"k8s.gcr.io/guestbook:v3",`

What is the correct way to modify `index.html` and deploy this new version?
Do I need to rebuild this image? Then where is the right place to upload it and how to deploy it with kubernetes tools on AWS?

Many thanks, as a newcomer to Kubernetes, looking for good steps to learn it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps at a high level to setup a fresh application with new image.

> 1. Do a git clone of the repository.
> 2. Modify the public/index.html locally.
> 3. Do a Docker build using `docker build ....`
> 4. Push the image to a registry (https://hub.docker.com/ or https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/ or some where else). The command depends on the registry. Also, make sure that the image is public.
> 5. Update the image appropriately in guestbook-controller.json.
> 6. Follow the steps as mentioned in the README.md.

If you want to update the image in an existing K8S application already running, then a rolling-update has to be done as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/#updating-the-container-image).

FYI ..... Without creating the image, the index.html can also be modified by copying the new index.html to all the running Pods as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677618/how-to-use-kubectl-cp-to-copy-files-automatically-from-a-local-system-to-kuberne/52678961#52678961).

FYI ..... the example uses [ReplicationController](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) which is outdated (mentioned in guestbook-controller.json), a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Yes, I already have running web application which was configured successfully. Can I ignore the fact that I have ReplicationController (not best practice) and do rolling-update for the quick win? Does this command will update `"image"` parameter in `guestbook-controller.json` with my new image version exactly as used in that command?

Comment: I can answer to my own question. `kubectl rolling-update guestbook --image=docker.io/<your account>/<your repository>:<your tag name>` fully updates internal Kubernetes configuration to new version so the new code should be successfully deployed. I used `hub.docker.com` Docker image registry.